# Problems with acessing buttons with JS and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I have a Bootstrap 5 button, that I'm trying to acess trough JS so I can disable it trough the Attribute.

My test code looks like this:
Script in Header:
`

```
<script>
    console.log(document.getElementsByName("test")[0]);          
</script>
```

`My Body with the button`

```
<body>
    <div name="test" class="btn bg-secondary">bestanden?</div>
</body>
```

`
If I run the command without an Index I get a list, in which the button is, if I try to get the first button, it will only show undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either use `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{})` or move you code to the end of the body. Your script is currently being executed before the bodies DOM content has loaded.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      const button = document.getElementsByName('test');
      console.log('button', button);
    </script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <button name="test">Test</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the example above, the list is empty.

Now lets add a `DOMContentLoaded` listener

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        const button = document.getElementsByName('test');
        console.log('button', button);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <button name="test">Test</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now we get our button and can do whatever we want with it.